# Two 4k Dell monitors but only one is in 4k

Tags: windows, laptop, multiple-monitors, hp-pavilion, docking-station

I recently got two 27in Dell UltraSharp 4k monitors (U2720Q). I have an HP EliteBook 840 G4 that is using a [HP dock](https://store.hp.com/us/en/pdp/hp-2013-ultraslim-docking-station?jumpid=ma__product-tile_dlp_nan_d9y32ut_hp-ultraslim-docking). For some odd reason, only one of the monitors is displaying in 4k. The other one is not. I have searched google but have not found anything that solves my problem. Here is the current settings:

Monitor that is not displaying in 4k:

[image: Monitor that is not displaying in 4k]

Monitor that displays in 4k:

[image: Monitor that displays in 4k]

I'm also not sure why monitor 1 is smaller in the display settings.

How can I fix it?

Comment: My first guess is that the docking station does not support the bandwidth required to power 2 displays at UHD. But, it seems like HP doesn’t want you to know jack about the functionality of this product because there’s no relevant information for it whatsoever.

Answer (score 0):

Try to connect two monitors without the docking station. You can connect first monitor with the USB type C port and the other one with the HDMI port directly from the laptop.
You can also try to change Graphic card display settings as a next step.